# How to use reactive argument as a value for an argument in code chunk in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am wondering how can I use a reactive logical expression as a value for an argument in code chunk.

for example in the following chunk

````
```{r,eval="input$task == 'Bond Analysis'",results='asis'}
asis_output("Row \n")
asis_output("-------------------------------------\n")
asis_output("### Price") 
```
````

task is a selectInput with multiple choices. No matter what, this chunk is evaluated. I even used

````
 ```{r} 
  renderText({"input$task == 'Bond Analysis'"}) 
  ```
````

to check if the value is TRUE or FALSE. when I choose anything besides 'Bond Analysis' the above value shows FALSE but the first code chunk is evaluated anyways

Comment: Try `renderText({input$task == 'Bond Analysis'})`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, didn't work

Comment: I tried something similar, but based upon a calculated (output) variable in a shiny document. Essentially, in the chunk before the "conditional" chunk I created a reactive (in your case that would be something like `task_reactive <- reactive({input$task == "Bond Analysis"})` and then use `eval=isolate(task_reactive)`. Of course, this depends on having logic that updates input$task based upon changed text.